# Business travel to UK without spouse and a Article 10 residence card

Tags: uk, business-travel

I am a holder of a Article 10 Residence Card (Residence Card of Family Member of a Union Citizen) issued by Lithuania and I am currently working in a Lithuanian based company that occasionally requires me to travel to other EU countries.

I now have to travel to the UK for a short business trip in which my EU citizen spouse **will not** be accompanying me.

Can I still enter the UK under this scenario? If not, what would be required for me to do so.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Will your planned trip be over before this coming Friday at noon?

Comment: @HenningMakholm how is that relevant? The freedom of movement doesn't end with hard Brexit, since the Immigration and Social Security Coordination Bill 2017-19 still needs to be passed for that.

Comment: @EwigeStudentin we don't know whether RMSS is traveling on a passport that allows visa-free visits to the UK, but the proposed duplicate is for someone who definitely is not eligible to visit without a visa.  I suppose we can presume that RMSS is similarly ineligible to do so, in which case the answer at the duplicate question applies, but with the information presented here that is not certain.